# The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I have ionic project and try to run it on simulator to debug an error

when I run the following command

```
ionic cordova run android --simulator --verbose --optimization=false
```

I get the following error

```
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:375:7)
    at ConfigKeeper.get (C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigKeeper.js:44:32)
    at C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigChanges.js:264:51
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PlatformMunger._is_conflicting (C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigChanges.js:257:21)
    at PlatformMunger.add_config_changes (C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigChanges.js:140:59)
    at C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare\platforms.js:66:24
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
  ionic:lib:cordova:project Error parsing file 'C:\\asu-mobile\\moodleapp2\\platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\output.json': [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output.json'] {
  ionic:lib:cordova:project   errno: -4058,
  ionic:lib:cordova:project   code: 'ENOENT',
  ionic:lib:cordova:project   syscall: 'open',
  ionic:lib:cordova:project   path: 'C:\\asu-mobile\\moodleapp2\\platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\output.json'
  ionic:lib:cordova:project } +0ms
  ionic:lib:cordova:project Error parsing file 'C:\\asu-mobile\\moodleapp2\\platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\output-metadata.json': [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output-metadata.json'] {
  ionic:lib:cordova:project   errno: -4058,
  ionic:lib:cordova:project   code: 'ENOENT',
  ionic:lib:cordova:project   syscall: 'open',
  ionic:lib:cordova:project   path: 'C:\\asu-mobile\\moodleapp2\\platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\output-metadata.json'
  ionic:lib:cordova:project } +3ms
[ERROR] Could not find or parse valid build output file.

        Tried the following paths:
        - C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output.json
        - C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output-metadata.json
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 3 functions +15ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 1666612: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 1666612 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "1666612" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 1666612 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +5s
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 1666612 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "1666612" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 1666612 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +2ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 1672184: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 1672184 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "1672184" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 1672184 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +28ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 1672184 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "1672184" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 1672184 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +1ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 1671456: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 1671456 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "1671456" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 1671456 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +4ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 1671456 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "1671456" not found.
  ionic:utils-process
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 1671456 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +67ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +254ms
```

Comment: can u show the config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml file?